# JB Rider не распознает весь синтаксис C#

Tags: c#, .net, rider

Использую JB Rider 2020. Я новый в C#, открыл готовый чужой проект. Но IDE не распознает ничего, даже `string`:

[image: Ошибка в string]

Очевидно, это не единственное проблемное место:

[image: 55 тысяч ошибок]

В начале по совету знающего программиста проверил установлен ли у меня путь к MSBuild, но с ним оказалось все в порядке(вроде):

[image: MSBuild установлен]

Так что мне пришлось обратить внимание на предупреждения в логах:

[image: Куча предупреждений с .NET]

Пакет разработчика .NET 4.7.1 я установил, но предупреждения не пропали. Возможно, содержимое этих предупреждений как раз и является причиной моей проблемы. Но я не знаю как исправить ее.

Так что мой вопрос следующий: **Как сделать так, чтобы JB Rider все таки начал распознавать синтаксис C#?**

Comment: Visual Studio - не вариант? С таким вопросом вам бы в поддержку JB обращаться, а не на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, можно ли здесь дать более обобщенный и подробный ответ на вопрос, который мне все таки удалось спустя некоторое время решить, но, надеюсь, это хоть как то поможет.

Используя JB Rider вместе с Unity, необходимо выбрать внешний редактор JB Rider в Unity в `Edit` => `Preferences` => `External Tools` => `External Script Editor`. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

[image: JB Rider выставлен в Unity]